# C++ does linking same static library in multiple file units increase size/bloat?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, libcurl

I'm using the libcurl library in C++, which is a pretty big library (.lib file is about 2MB), the project is compiled with `CURL_STATICLIB`

As for now I only have one .cpp file which includes the headers & links the library with `#pragma comment(lib, "lib/libcurl.lib")`

But I'm planning on creating additional units that will be separate from this one, but would also require to link the library again and include the headers.
What I'm wondering is, will this somehow increase the bloat in the app when compared to just a single unit linking the library? Or is it optimized and won't really affect anything that much?

Comment: What do you mean with *"creating additional units"*, more CPP files or your own separate libraries (eg. to "layer" your software)?

Comment: More cpp files using the curl lib in the same project

Comment: You can have bloat if your project has dlls and each of these dlls include your static libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of a static library only have a single representation, if any, in the final executable. This  is managed by the linker. Calling the library from multiple C++ files does not affect this.